# How to Prove Plancherel's Formula?

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-analysis

I have difficulty in proving Plancherel's formula in Fourier transform. Here is what I have thought:

In this question, I denote complex conjugation by an overline and (inverse) Fourier transform is defnined as

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}[f](\omega)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\,dt, \\
\mathcal{F}^{-1}[F](t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(t)e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega.
\end{align}

Let $F=\mathcal{F}[f]$ and $G=\mathcal{F}[g]$.

\begin{align}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\overline{g(t)}\,dt&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega\right)\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{G(-\omega')}e^{i\omega' t}\,d\omega'\right)\,dt\\
    &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{G(\omega')}e^{-i\omega' t}\,d\omega'\right)\,dt%\quad\text{(let $\omega''=-\omega'$ and re-write $\omega''$ to $\omega'$)} 
\\
    &=-\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{G(\omega')}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(\omega-\omega')t}\,dt\,d\omega'\,d\omega \\
    &=-\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{G(\omega')}2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega')\,d\omega'\,d\omega \\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)\overline{G(\omega)}\,d\omega.
\end{align}

So, an undesirable negative sign remains. Where do I make mistakes?

Comment: Why do you get $\omega'$ instead of $\omega$ as the argument for $G$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\overline{g(t)} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \overline{\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(\omega) e^{i \omega t}\, d \omega } = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \overline{G(\omega)} e^{-i \omega t} \, d \omega
$$

Comment: I transformed $\overline{g(t)}$ with $G$ according to the property of Fourier transform of conjugation (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties), though your answer also seems to be completely correct.

Comment: @Merzong I think you have just gotten confused about what the property is saying. What you were using was describing a relationship _between_ functions.. It says that **if** $h(x)$ is the complex conjugate of some other function $f(x)$, **then** it's Fourier Transform $\hat h(\xi) = \overline {\hat f(\xi)}$. But we don't care about that here. Here, we have $g(t) = \mathcal{F}(G(\omega))$, not $g(t) = \overline {f(t)}$.

Comment: @Mattos I understand your comment, but on the other hand I am still confused. $\overline{g(t)}$ is the complex conjugate of $g(t)$ itself, so it seems to me that Fourier transform of $\overline{g(t)}$ is $\overline{G(-\omega)}$, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Merzong That's what I was trying to explain to you. It should be

\begin{align}
g(t) &= \mathcal{F}(G(\omega)) \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} G(\omega) e^{i \omega t} d \omega \\\\
\implies \overline g(t) &= \overline {\mathcal{F}(G(\omega))} \\
&= \overline {\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} G(\omega) e^{i \omega t} d \omega} \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline {G(\omega)} e^{-i \omega t} d \omega
\end{align}

Comment: @Mattos That is surely true. However, I thought:

\begin{align}
G(\omega)=\mathcal{F}[g](\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(t)e^{-i\omega t}\,dt.
\end{align}

Thinking complex conjugate, I get

\begin{align}
\overline{G(\omega)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\overline{g(t)}e^{i\omega t}\,dt.
\end{align}

Replacing $\omega$ by $-\omega$, I finally get

\begin{align}
\overline{G(-\omega)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\overline{g(t)}e^{-i\omega t}\,dt \\
\implies\overline{g(t)}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\overline{G(-\omega)}e^{i\omega t}\,dt.
\end{align}

I think the essence of my confusion is why the “$\implies$” is wrong.

Comment: I want to prove Plancherel`s formula without using Fourier transform, do you have an advice?