# Proving Plancherel's identity.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I want to prove that $$\Arrowvert \hat{f} \Arrowvert_{l^2(\mathbb{Z})} = \Arrowvert f \Arrowvert _{L^2([-L,L])},$$

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Show that the Fourier series a continuously differentiable periodic function $f$ converges uniformly to $f$. Use this to show what you want for such $f$. Then approximate.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts  I have seen this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353893/how-to-prove-plancherels-formula?rq=1   but here he uses Fourier transform     How can I prove it without using Fourier transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem you want to prove is
$$
            \int_{-L}^{L}|f(x)|^2dx = \frac{1}{2L}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\int_{-L}^{L}f(t)e^{-in\pi t/L}dt\right|^2
$$
This is cast into the $L^2$ framework by considering the orthonormal set
$$
             e_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}e^{in\pi x/L}.
$$
In this framework, the theorem is $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|(f,e_n)|^2$ where $(f,g) = \int_{-L}^{L}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$ is the inner product on the complex space $L^2[-L,L]$. There are several ways to prove this theorem because of the following:

**Theorem:** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $\{ e_n \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ be an orthonormal subset of $H$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n}|(f,e_n)|^2$ for all $f \in H$.
2. $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n}|(f,e_n)|^2$ for all $f$ in a dense subspace $M$ of $H$.
3. $\sum_{n}(f,e_n)(e_n,g)=(f,g)$ for all $f,g\in H$.
4. $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}(f,e_n)e_n$ converges to $f$ in the norm of $H$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$.
5. $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}(f,e_n)e_n$ converges to $f$ in the norm of $H$ as
   $N\rightarrow\infty$ for all $f$ in a dense subspace of $H$.
6. The only $f\in H$ for which $(f,e_n)=0$ holds for all $n$ is $f=0$.

Proving (5) is one of the eaiser ways in this particular case because it can be shown that the space $C^1_p[-L,L]$ of periodic continuous differentiable functions is dense in $H$, and classical uniform pointwise convergence results for the Fourier series then imply $L^2$ norm convergence. Indeed, for any such $f$, it follows that
\begin{align}
 (f,e_n) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)e^{-in\pi x/L}f(t)dt 
   \\
   & = \left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}f(t)\frac{e^{-in\pi t/L}}{-in\pi/L}\right|_{-L}^{L}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}in\pi/ L}\int_{-L}^{L}f'(t)e^{-int/L}dt \\
   & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}in\pi/ L}\int_{-L}^{L}f'(t)e^{-int/L}dt.
\end{align}
So the following series converges pointwise absolutely and uniformly on $[-L,L]$
$$
               g(x)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}(f,e_n)e_n(x)
$$
because $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}|(f,e_n)|^2 \le \|f\|^2$ always holds for any $f$ and for any orthonormal set $\{ e_n \}$, and because
$$
               \sum_{n=-N}^{N}|(f,e_n)e_n(x)| \le \sum_{n=-N}^{N}|(f,e_n)|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2/L}n\pi} \\
     \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2/L}}|(f,e_0)|+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2/L}\pi}\sum_{n=-N,n\ne 0}^{N}\frac{1}{n}|(f',e_n)| \\
    \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2/L}}|(f,e_0)|+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2/L}\pi}\left(\sum_{n=-N,n\ne 0}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=-N,n\ne 0}^{N}|(f',e_n)|^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$
So the series $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}(f,e_n)e_n(x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly to some continuous functions $g$. Actually it must converge everywhere to $f$ because of classical convergence theorems for the Fourier series. Because the series converges absolutely and uniformly to $g=f$, then (5) holds for all $f$ in the dense subspace $C^1_p[-L,L]$ because the series converges uniformly to $f$ for all $f\in C_p^1[-L,L]$, which certainly implies $L^2$ norm convergence.

Comment: why did you put $1/\sqrt(2L)$ in the orthonormal set?

Comment: @weakmathematician : $\int_{-L}^{L}\left|\frac{e^{in\pi x/L}}{\sqrt{2L}}\right|^2dx = \int_{-L}^{L}\frac{1}{2L}dx = \frac{2L}{2L}=1$.

Comment: Do this theorem have a name ?

Comment: what is the intuition  behind your sentence "Proving (5) is one of the eaiser ways in this particular case"? why Proving (5) is one of the eaiser ways in this particular case?

Comment: @weakmathematician : If a function is continuously differentiable and periodic, then its Fourier series converges uniformly to the function; and uniform convergence implies $L^2$ convergence. So the proof reduces to classical convergence results of Fourier series.

Comment: But I have to prove this theorem before using it, is it found in a book? if so what is its name ?

Comment: How can I show that " the space $C_{p}^{1}([−L,L])$ of periodic continuous differentiable functions is dense in H"? I know how to show that $C(T)$ is dense in $L^{p}(T)$ where T is the circle, will this help me in showing that " the space $C_{p}^{1}([−L,L])$ of periodic continuous differentiable functions is dense in H"?

Comment: @weakmathematician : If you know $C(T)$ is dense in $L^2$, then you can show that $C^1(T)$ is dense in $C(T)$ to achieve the result.

Comment: from which book is that theorem ?

Comment: The first identity after the theorem contain extra $f(t)$.

Comment: and the integration is from $-L$ to $L$.

Comment: what do you mean by saying this " Actually it must converge everywhere to ff because of classical convergence theorems for the Fourier series "?

Comment: @Idonotknow : You don't need a theorem. If $C(T)$ is dense in $L^2$, and if $M$ is a subspace of $C(T)$ that is dense in $C(T)$, then, given $f\in L^2$, you can find $g\in C(T)$ such that $\|g-f\|_{L^2} < \epsilon/2$, and then $h\in M$ such that $\|g-h\| \le 2L\|g-h\|_{C(T)} < \epsilon/2$, which gives $h\in M$ such that $\|f-h\|_{L^2} < \epsilon$. This is because $\|f\|_{L^2}\le 2L\|f\|_{C}$.

Comment: @Idonotknow : If $f$ is periodic with period $2L$ on $\mathbb{R}$, and if $f$ is continuously differentiable with continuous derivative, then the Fourier series for $f$ converges uniformly to $f$. That's a basic Fourier series type of result.

Comment: why did not you use no.(1) in your theorem in proving the required it is more intuitive? what hinders you?

Comment: I did not understand how in the first inequality the term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2/ L} n \pi}$ came, could u clarify please?

Comment: In the second inequality the first term, I understand that you substitute for $n = 0$, but there is $n$ in the denominator and if you substitute by it, it will give you $\infty$, what did you do?Also the $f'$ term in the second term of the inequality, from where it comes?

Comment: @Idonotknow  actually he uses what is said in Stein & Shakarachi "Fourier series " p.39 the first 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a quantum mechanical heart, you can consider an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ over $[-L, L]$, and its dual space $H^{*}$. You then can construct projective spaces of those $P(H)$ and $P(H^{*})$ and define the vectors on them $|f\rangle$ and $\langle f|$ respectively. The inner-product may be cast as $\langle f|f\rangle$. To write the $L^2$ norm you essentially need to resolve the identity as $I=\int_{-L}^{L}|x\rangle\!\langle x|dx$. Inserting the identity in the inner product you get
$$\langle f|f\rangle=\langle f|I|f\rangle=\int_{-L}^{L}\langle f|x\rangle\!\langle x|f\rangle dx=\int_{-L}^{L}|f(x)|^{2}dx$$
On the other hand, you can pick up an orthonormal countable basis for the projective space $\{|n\rangle\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$, so that any vector on it (including $|f\rangle$) may be expanded in the basis due to the completeness
$$|f\rangle=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_{n}|n\rangle$$
The coefficients of the expansion due to the orthonormality are clearly
$$c_{n}=\langle n|f\rangle=\langle n|I|f\rangle=\int_{-L}^{L}\langle n|x\rangle\!\langle x|f\rangle dx=\int_{-L}^{L}n^{*}(x)f(x)dx$$
The inner product is then
$$\langle f|f\rangle=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c^{*}_{m}c_{n}\langle m|n\rangle=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c^{*}_{m}c_{n}\delta_{mn}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|c_{n}|^{2}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|\int_{-L}^{L}n^{*}(x)f(x)dx\right |^{2}$$
Hence
$$\int_{-L}^{L}|f(x)|^{2}dx=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|\int_{-L}^{L}n^{*}(x)f(x)dx\right|^{2}$$
or in your notation
$$||f||_{L^{2}[-L, L]}=||f||_{l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})}$$

Comment: And if you don't see why identity is $I=\int_{[-L, L]}|x><x|dx$, consider expanding the vector on the projective space $|f>$ in the uncountable basis $\{|x>\}$ (which you can do by completeness) $|f>=\int_{[-L, L]}f(x)|x>dx$, on the other hand $<y|f>=\int_{[-L, L]}f(x)<y|x>dx=\int_{[-L, L]}f(x)\delta(x-y)dx=f(y)$, so $|f>=\int_{[-L, L]}f(x)|x>dx=\int_{[-L, L]}<x|f>|x>dx=\int_{[-L, L]}|x><x|f>dx$, this must hold for any $|f>$, so $I=\int_{[-L, L]}|x><x|dx$. Similarly you can show that in the countable basis $I=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|n><n|$.