# Specific Proof of Plancherel's identity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

This is a followup question on an answer from the following question about Plancherel's identity from a few years ago:
[Proving Plancherel's identity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279039/proving-plancherels-identity)

the accepted answer (which is very thorough) states that:

(Here $(,)$ is the 'standard' integral inner product)

"**Theorem:** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $\{ e_n \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ be an orthonormal subset of $H$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n}|(f,e_n)|^2$ for all $f \in H$.
2. $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n}|(f,e_n)|^2$ for all $f$ in a dense subspace $M$ of $H$.
3. $\sum_{n}(f,e_n)(e_n,g)=(f,g)$ for all $f,g\in H$.
4. $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}(f,e_n)e_n$ converges to $f$ in the norm of $H$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$.
5. $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}(f,e_n)e_n$ converges to $f$ in the norm of $H$ as
   $N\rightarrow\infty$ for all $f$ in a dense subspace of $H$.
6. The only $f\in H$ for which $(f,e_n)=0$ holds for all $n$ is $f=0$."

I am very curious about #6 here. How exactly is equivalent to the others? Sorry if this is a duplicate question- i have not been able to find this specific proof.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can always write $f$ as the sum of its projection on the span of all $\{e_n\}$ plus the orthogonal complement $u_f$:
$$f=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} ( e_n, f) e_n + u_f$$
where $( e_n, u_f) = 0$ for all $n$.

This is equivalent to writing
$$\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} |( e_n, f)|^2 + \|u_f\|^2$$

Then $(6)$ is equivalent to saying that $u_f=0$ (you can check as an exercise). And it's easy to see that it's equivalent to $(1)$.