# Proof of Plancherel formula

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was looking at this question posted here some time ago. 
[How to Prove Plancherel's Formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353893/how-to-prove-plancherels-formula)

I get it until in the third line he practically says that $\int _{- \infty}^{+\infty} e^{i(\omega - \omega')t} dt= 2 \pi \delta(\omega - \omega')$.

I mean, I would understand if we were integrating over a period of length $2 \pi$, but here the integration is over $\mathbb{R}$.

P.S. I would have asked this directly to the author of the post, but it's been over a year since he last logged in.

Comment: Are you unclear on why the integral converges, why it converges to that value, how how one would prove the statement?

Comment: I don't understand why it converges at that value, given the definition of complex exponential involves sin and cos

Comment: Do you know what the [Delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) is?

Comment: Wait, I thought it was Kronecker delta! No, I don't know what the Dirac delta is. I've just heard that another important measure, except for Lebesgue, is the Dirac measure.

Comment: They are similar (thus the similar notation). Kronecker is 1 when two indices are the same. Dirac's Delta is a special $\infty$ (such that it integrates to 1) when the argument is zero. The wiki article should clear things up for you.

Answer (score 4):

A classical way to interpret what you have is through the Fourier transform and its inverse. If $f$ is continuous at $x$ where it has left- and right-hand derivatives, and if $f$ is suitably integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
     \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds = f(x).
$$
This can be written as
\begin{align}
      f(x)&=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-ist}dt e^{isx}ds \\
    &=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{is(x-t)}ds\right)f(t)dt
\end{align}
This is being represented in a short-hand form as
$$
       \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{is(x-t)}ds=\delta(x-t).
$$
There are several ways to interpret the above, but none of them including treating the integral by itself.

The symmetric truncated integral is
$$
      \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R} e^{is(x-t)}ds = \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\sin(R(x-t))}{x-t}.
$$
So you're really looking at a very classical limit of an integral:
$$
           \lim_{R\uparrow\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\frac{\sin(R(x-t))}{x-t}dt = f(x).
$$

Answer (score 1):

As you noted $\int _{- \infty}^{+\infty} e^{i(\omega - \omega')t} dt= 2 \pi \delta(\omega - \omega')$ is of course not true. This is an abuse of notation, what it really means is that the Fourier transform of the (tempered) distribution $f(\omega) = e^{i \omega' t}$ is  the (tempered) distribution $\hat{f}(\omega) = 2 \pi \delta(\omega-\omega')$.

---

In general, if $f$ is a tempered distribution, then its Fourier transform (in the sense of distributions) is the tempered distribution $\hat{f}$ iff for every Schwartz function $\varphi$ :

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \varphi(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega)\hat{\varphi}(\omega)d\omega$$

(where in general $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \varphi(t)dt$ is **not** a Riemann integral, but the pairing of a distribution with a test function)

Comment: I never used things like Schwartz functions or tempered distributions, I have just started studying Fourier transform. Could you please explain it in a bit more step-by-step way?

Comment: @tommy1996q : Do you know what is the Dirac delta $\delta$ defined by $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t) \varphi(t)dt = \varphi(0)$$ whenever $\varphi$ is continuous ? What is its Fourier transform ? It is not complicated : $$\mathcal{F}[\delta](\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t) e^{-i \omega t}dt = e^{-i \omega t}|_{t= 0} = 1$$
thus, by the Fourier inversion theorem of distributions $$\delta = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[1] $$ and you get what I wrote in my answer when $\omega' = 0$

Comment: Ok I think I got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think he used that $$ 1 = \hat{\delta(w)} $$ so, $$\int _{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i(\omega-\omega ')t} dt $$ is the antitransform of $\delta$  values in $(\omega - \omega') $ plus $2\pi$ for definition of antitransform.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that $\omega = \omega'$, it's clear that we don't expect the integral to converge - the Dirac's Delta function is infinite at zero:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i ( \omega - \omega )t} dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1\, dt = \infty
\end{equation}

In the case that $\omega \neq \omega'$, neither the positive nor the negative sides converge separately, but they don't have to.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i u} du &=& i \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(u) du + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(u) du \\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(u) &=& \lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-a}^a \sin(u) du \\
&=& \lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} - \cos(a) + \cos(-a)\\
&=& \lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} 0 \\
&=& 0 \\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(u) &=& \int_{-\infty + \frac{\pi}{2}}^{\infty + \frac{\pi}{2}} \cos \left(x - \frac{\pi}{2} \right) dx \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) dx \\
&=& 0 \\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i u} du &=& 0 + i 0 = 0
\end{eqnarray}$$

This may feel uncomfortable but it's as rigorous as $a - a + b - b = 0$.

The final ambiguity is the value of $\infty$ from Equation 1. Without getting into the weeds of how one defines frequency (which moves that $2\pi$ all over the place), we know from the definition of the Fourier Transform that both:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{F}(g(t)) &=& G(\omega) \\
\mathcal{F}(G(\omega)) &=& g(t)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Since $\mathcal{F(F}(g(t))) = \mathcal{F}(G(\omega)) = g(t)$, we may equivalently show that

$$\mathcal{F}(2 \pi \delta(\omega - \omega')) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i \omega t} \delta(\omega - \omega') d\omega = e^{-i \omega' t} = g(t)$$

by the [sifting property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) which is what we sought.

Comment: the integral doesn't converge

Comment: Are you asking about whether the integral converges when $\omega = \omega'$ or when $\omega \neq \omega'$?

Comment: The improper Riemann integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i a t}dt$ doesn't converge for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Also the Dirac delta distribution $\delta$ is not a function. Its definition is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t) \varphi(t)dt = \varphi(0)$ whenever $\varphi$ is continuous

Comment: @user1952009 But it doesn't converge in different ways. Also, you should edit that title on Wikipedia and Wolfram Mathworld if you're adamant about the function thing. It accepts a number and returns a number; that's the definition of a function.

Comment: $\delta(t) =0$ for $t \ne 0$, it doesn't mean this is a function (proof : the Dirac delta $\delta$ is a distribution, not a function). Also $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i a t}dt$ diverges, that's what the OP noted.

Comment: If you're going to insist that it isn't a function, you'll have to provide a reason - especially since I provided the definition and two sources much more believable than you.

Comment: IMO the best definition is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t) \varphi(t)dt \overset{def} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1_{|t| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon} \varphi(t)dt =  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \varphi(t)dt$$ and this is $\varphi(0)$ whenever $\varphi$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function "From a purely mathematical viewpoint, the Dirac delta is not strictly a function, because any extended-real function that is equal to zero everywhere but a single point must have total integral zero"

Comment: Love the title of that article. While we're cherry-picking, perhaps you'd prefer to define it as a measure or a generalized function? Listen, I get that it has weird properties, but you've chosen a tangential topic to be pedantic about.

Comment: Not at all, I'm not pedantic, I'm trying to explain something important in Fourier analysis. Yes measure, generalized function, distribution are valid ways to define and denote the Dirac delta.

Comment: What you wrote about the convergence is a non-sense. That for $\omega \ne \omega'$ : $$\lim_{N \to \infty, N \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{-2\pi N/(\omega-\omega)}^{2\pi N/(\omega-\omega)} e^{-i (\omega-\omega')}dt = 0$$
doesn't mean that  $2\pi \delta(\omega-\omega')$ is the Fourier transform of $e^{i \omega' t}$. You should really start thinking about what is the Fourier transform of distributions (see my answer)

Comment: @user1952009 I'm so sorry - I must not have been clear. The integral of an even function from $-a$ to $a$ is zero, no matter what $a$ is. And all that demonstrated was that $\delta(a \neq 0) = 0$. I covered the other case with other math. I read your answer. I understand it. It uses mathematics which came way later than Plancherel for me. Why use a big hammer that doesn't make sense yet when this little hammer works? Plancherel should be accessible to somebody with a little calculus, and that's all I used.

Comment: You mean the integral of an odd function. Here $e^{i(\omega-\omega')t}$ is not odd nor even. As I said what you wrote about the convergence is a non-sense, no you didn't prove that $\mathcal{F}[e^{i \omega' t}](\omega) = 0$ when $\omega - \omega ' \ne 0$

Comment: If you want to avoid the theory of distributions, you need to assume the Fourier inversion theorem for those, so it reduces to $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega')](t)= e^{i \omega' t}$

Comment: Brainfart. Yes, you're right. The sine term disappears when we break the integral up at 0, the cosine term is at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Ok now note that $$\lim_{N \to \infty, N \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{-2\pi \frac{N+1/4}{\omega-\omega'}}^{2\pi \frac{N+1/4}{\omega-\omega'}}  e^{-i (\omega-\omega')}dt = \frac{1}{2 (\omega-\omega')}$$ Thus the Fourier transform of $e^{i \omega' t}$ is $\frac{1}{2 (\omega-\omega')}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Why are you putting all that garbage on the integration limit? The $\frac{1}{\omega-\omega'}$ term is there if you are taking every step, but the $2\pi N$ term is just silly. $\sin(\phi - \frac{\pi}{2}) = - \cos(\phi) $

Comment: Because $\int_{-b}^b e^{i at}dt = \frac{2 \sin(ab)}{a}$ which depends on $b \bmod 2\pi / a$

Comment: @user1952009 If you agree that the cosine integral evaluates to zero, then you must clearly be arguing that $\infty + \frac{\pi}{2} \neq \infty$, and I know you aren't that ... wrong.